# generic class equals method that constrains input parameter and object to have same type T

Tags: c#

The following [c#] code will not compile with the error "operator == cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'".

```
public class Widget<T> where T: IComparable
{
    public T value;
    public Widget(T input) { value = input; }
    public bool Equals<T>(Widget<T> w) where T : System.IComparable
    {
        return (w.value == value);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to constrain the type T of the w input parameter to be the same type T as the object being compared thus guaranteeing they can be compared against each other and eliminating the compiler error?  Using (dynamic) in front of value as below allows it to compile but it seemed like there would be a better way that would catch an issue at compile time:

`public bool Equals<T>(Widget<T> w) where T : System.IComparable
   {
      return (w.value == (dynamic) value);
   }`

Comment: What *exactly* do you want `==` to check? Reference equality? Value equality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're *really* interested in value equality here, you can just use [`EqualityComparer.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx):

```
EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
return comparer.Equals(w.value, value);
```

Note that currently your `Equals` method is generic too, trying to declare *another* type parameter T. I don't think you really want to do that.

Comment: Thanks.  This took care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Widget<T> where T: IComparable
{
    public T value;
    public Widget(T input) { value = input; }
    public bool Equals(Widget<T> other)
    {
        if(value == null)
        {
          return other == null || other.Value == null;
        }
        if(other == null) return false; //ensure next line doesn't get null pointer exception
        return value.CompareTo(other.Value) == 0;
    }
}
```

You may need to play around with the null checking logic based on how you want it to behave with various permutations of `value`, `other`, and `other.value` being null.

Comment: That's assuming the comparison is consistent with equals - it may not always be.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed.  Considering the OP went to all the effort to ensure T is `IComparable` I assumed that the comparable implementation mattered more than the `Equals` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
public class Widget<T> : IEquatable<Widget<T>>, IComparable<Widget<T>>
    where T : IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>
{
    public T value;
    public Widget(T input) { value=input; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is Widget<T>)
        {
            return Equals(obj as Widget<T>);
        }
        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return value.GetHashCode();
    }
    public bool Equals(Widget<T> other)
    {
        return value.Equals(other.value);
    }

    public int CompareTo(Widget<T> other)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(other.value);
    }
    public static bool operator==(Widget<T> a, Widget<T> b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }
    public static bool operator!=(Widget<T> a, Widget<T> b)
    {
        return !a.Equals(b);
    }
    public static bool operator<(Widget<T> a, Widget<T> b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b)==-1;
    }
    public static bool operator>(Widget<T> a, Widget<T> b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b)==1;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Widget<int> a=new Widget<int>(100);
        Widget<int> b=new Widget<int>(200);

        if(a==b||a>b)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to null check `value` and `w`

Comment: I do need to check for `value`, but not `other` or `obj` as `Equals()` and `CompareTo()` check for null also.

Comment: in the line `return value.Equals(other.value);` if other is null you'll get a null pointer error.  `other.value` can be null, but if `other` is null your code blows up.  The same issue applies to the same line in `CompareTo`.

Comment: No it wont. Because the override will only hit if `other` is of type `Widget<T>` and not `null`. Otherwise it will go to the generic `Equals(object other)` where `null` _is_ checked. Try it!

Comment: `Widget<int> a = null; Widget<int> b=new Widget<int>(200); bool result = b.Equals(a);`  That will crash.  Likewise `a == b` and `b == a` will also crash.  Go run the program if you don't believe me.  If the `Equals(Widget<T>)` method was private then you would be forced to go through the `Equals(Object)` method to do the null checking, as is, you are not.  The compiler always chooses the type closest to the parameter when it has several options, so you would need to cast the `Widget<T>` to an object to get the object overload.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Widget<T> where T: IEquatable<T>
{
    public T value;
    public Widget(T input) { value = input; }
    public bool Equals(Widget<T> w)
    {
        return (w.value.Equals(this.value));
    }
}
```

If you need *equality* comparison, then you should use `IEquatable`. `IComparable` is more appropriate for when you want order comparisons as well (less than, greater than).

I think that your main mistake is that you’re introducing a new type parameter in your `Equals<T>` method. Don’t; rather, let the `T` in your `Widget<T>` parameter be the same type that the class was instantiated with. This guarantees that `w.Value` would be of the same type as `this.value`.

Comment: you need to null check `w` and `w.value`.

Comment: @Servy: That wasn’t the point of the question. If we wanted to get pedantic, then the `value` field should be private, the `Widget(T)` constructor should throw `ArgumentNullException` if `input` is `null`, and the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method implementation should return `false` if its parameter is `null`. So no, I don’t “need” to null check `w` or `w.value`.

Comment: Well you don't "need" to do anything.  It would be best to null check those values.  Not doing so has a reasonably high probability of causing exceptions that you are capable of preventing.  If nothing else, it's a note to the OP that he should add null checking even if the answer doesn't.  As for `value` being private, that would indeed be a better design, but not doing it won't cause the program to crash, which is also the case for not throwing an `ArgumentNullException`.  (In fact, it may be perfectly acceptable for `input` to be null.)

Comment: @Servy: It would make sense to null-check those values only if they are _allowed_, by design, to be null. If not, then you should use `ArgumentNullException` when introducing them, and refrain from littering your code with redundant null reference checks. You could argue that redundant null checks are still worth including just in case the class’s design changes in the future, but like I said, this whole argument is beyond the point of the original question.

Comment: It's not an error to compare null with a concrete value.  The two are not equal.  If two nulls are passed in then they are equal.  There is no need to crash, throw `ArgumentNullException`, etc.  There is a legitimate true/false answer for each case.